# Is there a word for the particular usage of the curly brace, or a shape like it, to indicate part of a diagram?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, technical, image-identification, braces

Or for measurements.

Consider the green things in this image:
[image: Labels indicating a rat and the dimensions and species thereof]

Sorry if this ends up being a duplicate, the suggested questions to me seemed to address slightly different topics.

Comment: This question might be more suitable for [Graphic Design.SE](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: OK, I will try there. I thought of English SE due to the post being a search for a word.

Comment: They are certainly *braces*. That's about all I can say.

Comment: It looks like a variation of [linear scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_scale).

Comment: Those are [*callouts*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/call-out) (dictionary.com) of a particular form.

Comment: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/82420 has been created.

Answer (score 4):

For the top one, you could say the curly brace is being used instead (or as) a **dimensioning line**.

Quoting http://www.design-technology.info/IndProd/page9.htm

> **Dimensioning**
>   The purpose of dimensioning is to provide a clear and complete description of an object. 
>   [...].
>   Definitions and Dimensions.
>   The **dimension line** is a thin line, broken in the middle to allow the placement of the dimension value, with arrowheads at each end (see diagram below). An arrowhead is approximately 3 mm long and 1mm wide. That is, the length is roughly three times the width. An extension line extends a line on the object to the dimension line.

The linked article has diagrams which make it clearer.

Comment: This applies to the top but not the bottom brace in OP's picture.

Comment: @nebuch Agreed. The answer does say it's just for the top one.